# Python script does not work unless run with sudo

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, centos, openpyxl

I have a script which I wrote in windows and is working fine, and I am now transferring to a CentOS.

The scripts transforms an excel file, to different forms of pivot_tables

I did the setup, and installed the pre-requisites.

Now when I try to run my scripts, they don't seem to work. It will prompt that the python component cannot be imported even though I just installed it.

Then I tried to run the script as sudo, then it worked like it worked on my windows environment. But my problem now is the file is totally unusable unless it is opened with sudo command.

Is there any way that I can run my scripts without using the sudo command?

This is the error I receive if I run the script without sudo:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "step1.1_executeConsolidation.py", line 12, in <module>
    from openpyxl import workbook
ImportError: cannot import name 'workbook'
```

(Workbook or workbook, I get the same results)

Comment: How did you install the "prerequisites" and did the "setup"? Under `sudo`? With `pip` and `-u` command? Seems like you may have installed all dependencies in the root account and cannot access them unless you sudo.

Comment: Can you copy and paste the exact error?

Comment: @Vivek, yes I believe I have installed everything using sudo. You mean to say, I should install the pip tool, and install components using pip without sudo?

Comment: @BenJ, I will include the error in the question

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/) it is definitely capital W Workbook.  You definitely get the error with Workbook?  If so, what are the permissions set for the python files step1.1_executeConsolidation.py and the main python script being run?

Comment: Can you post the install command you used?

Comment: I reinstalled python 3.4 and reinstalled using "sudo yum install python34", then I ran the 2 lines: "sudo yum install python34-setuptools" and "sudo easy_install-3.4 pip"

Comment: When I try to run pip or pip3.4 without su, it says permission denied

Comment: @BenJ, it is allowed to execute as a program. read and write for all users. If this is what you mean by permission

Comment: hello people, I found a workaround on the issue by using virtualenv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did to fix my issue is to use a virtualenv.

I installed the virtualenv, and create a folder to create an separate instance.

At this point, the folder for project is only accessible using sudo. So what I did was perform chown command to remove my folder from admin and transfer to my account.

Now whenever I activate my virtual env, and run my scripts and open the output file, I don't have to use sudo anymore.